# Piping a stream to a warp response

Tags: rust

I would like to create a warp endpoint that would stream a specific requested file (from a Google bucket in my case). I don't want to load the whole file in memory before sending it back to the user because it could be rather big.

I'm using the `cloud_storage` crate to get the file :

```
pub async fn download_streamed(
    bucket: &str,
    file_name: &str
) -> Result<impl Stream<Item = Result<u8>> + Unpin>
```

[(see doc here)](https://docs.rs/cloud-storage/0.10.2/cloud_storage/object/struct.Object.html#method.download_streamed)

Here's the code that is bothering me:

```
pub async fn download(file_name: String) -> Result<impl Reply, Infallible> {
    let stream = Client::default()
        .object()
        .download_streamed(
            &var("BUCKET").expect("Missing `BUCKET` env var"),
            &file_name,
        )
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let body = hyper::Body::wrap_stream(stream);
                                        ^^^^^^

    Ok(warp::reply::Response::new(body))
}
```

This is the compiler's message:

```
112 |     let body = hyper::Body::wrap_stream(stream);
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<u8>` is not implemented for `hyper::body::Bytes`
    |
   ::: /Users/.../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/hyper-0.14.12/src/body/body.rs:193:12
    |
193 |         O: Into<Bytes> + 'static,
    |            ----------- required by this bound in `Body::wrap_stream`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <hyper::body::Bytes as From<&'static [u8]>>
              <hyper::body::Bytes as From<&'static str>>
              <hyper::body::Bytes as From<Box<[u8]>>>
              <hyper::body::Bytes as From<Vec<u8>>>
            and 5 others
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<hyper::body::Bytes>` for `u8`
```

As I understand it - and because the message is pretty clear too - the stream's associated `Item` is of type `u8` and there is no `From<u8> for hyper::body::Bytes` available.

Would there be a way to do some conversion magic then?

--

Edit: I tried a few things :

- First, I naively tried to `map_ok` the `u8` to a `vec![u8]`. It worked but the performances were beyond poor
- Secondly, I modified `download_streamed` implementation to return a stream of Bytes :

```
    pub async fn download_streamed(
        &self,
        bucket: &str,
        file_name: &str,
    ) -> crate::Result<impl Stream<Item = std::result::Result<Bytes, reqwest::Error>> + Unpin> {

        [... omitted ...]

        let response = self
            .0
            .client
            .get(&url)
            .headers(self.0.get_headers().await?)
            .send()
            .await?
            .error_for_status()?;

        Ok(response.bytes_stream())
```

Result: blazing fast ...

Comment: As I see it is because your stream is of `Item=Result<u8>`, you would have to  unwrap the results somehow?

Comment: @Netwave I guess a `Result` is indeed expected if you look at the `wrap_stream` definition:

```
pub fn wrap_stream<S, O, E>(stream: S) -> Body where
    S: Stream<Item = Result<O, E>> + Send + 'static,
    O: Into<Bytes> + 'static,
    E: Into<Box<dyn StdError + Send + Sync>> + 'static,
```

I would say the issue arises, as the compiler says, because the trait bound for `O` does not exist (`O: Into<Bytes>`).

Edit : sorry, I thought you could paste code blocks here too 

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here? You appear to have a "blazing fast" solution already, so what are you asking?

Comment: @Jmb You are right... when I originally wrote the post I did not plan to modify the external crate. This feels dirty to me and I don't know if there is something to do to avoid it.

Comment: Well the original API of `download_streamed` was very bad: returning individual `Result<u8>` for each byte will always be slow. There is a reason why I/O is usually buffered to process blocks of bytes at once.

Comment: @Jmb Ok, thank you. Indeed, I was a bit surprised too when I looked at it.